# React appendChild to svg

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I am new to React and currently working on an interactive world map.
I use an inline svg.
I added some css, so when I hover over the continents they Transform: scale(1.1)
I realised that some continent are in the back. When hovering over them, they scale but it looks weird.

Here you can see Europe, Asia and Afrika not beeing hovered.
[image]

When hovering over Asia you can see it gets scaled up but it's in the back of Afrika
[image: When hovering over Asia you can see it gets scaled up but it's in the back of Afrika, thats because of the Rendering Order of svg 1.1]

thats because of the Rendering Order of svg 1.1

> [3.3 Rendering Order](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/render.html#RenderingOrder)
>
> Elements in an SVG document fragment have an implicit drawing order,
> with the first elements in the SVG document fragment getting "painted"
> first. Subsequent elements are painted on top of previously painted
> elements.

Unfortunately svg 1.1 does not support z-index.
I haven't looked into svg 2.0 at all (which would support z-index) as far as I know.

so I red some threads about how it would be possible to order the continents on hover, so that the hovered one is in front.

I found [How to Bring svg Elements to the Front](https://adam.garrett-harris.com/2015-06-06-how-to-bring-svg-elements-to-the-front/)

And started to try doing this with React.
I use a onMouseEnter event on the path which calls the handleHover function and passes in the event, inside the function I call the parentElement property of the currentTarget and appendChild the currentTarget.

```
function MapComponent() {

  function handleHover(event) {
    event.currentTarget.parentElement.appendChild(event.currentTarget);
  }

  return (
    <svg version="1.1" id="World" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
      <a href="/Australia" title="Australia" className="nav-link">
        <path
          id="Australia"
          onMouseEnter={(event) => handleHover(event)}
          d="..."
        />
      </a>
    </svg>
  );
}
```

But it's not working as expected. When hovering over the path (continent) it is still in the back.

EDIT:
when swaping appendChild() with removeChild() the continent dissapears on mouse enter. That tells me the correct element is selected.

I also tried it completely different, as explained [here](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-onhover-event-handling-with-examples)(in the first example). Unfortunately this is not working either.

```
  const [isHovered, setHovered] = useState(false);


  return (
    <svg version="1.1" id="World" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
      <a href="/Australia" title="Australia" className="nav-link">
        <path
          id="Australia"
          onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}
          d="..."
        />
        {isHovered && (
          <path
            id="Australia"
            onMouseEnter={() => isHovered(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => isHovered(false)}
            d="..."
          />
        )}
```

Comment: With your current code (the 1st example) you're copying the element which causes a duplicate id. Take the attributes of your current target and create a new path with them. Use a unique id for the new path that you use as a selector for applying your css animation. For testing purposes, you can use a different color for the newly created path to see if it is on top of the original.

Comment: I dont fully underand the reason why you need to move elements order just to make them animated on hover..
but for your first example it seems you're appending child to `a` element (`<a href="/Australia"`) which already has just one child, and you should be appending to the root

Comment: @paulitto it's just the order of the paths in the svg. when hovering they stay in the back. 
I added some pictures.

Comment: You're reparenting the path within the a but that does nothing. You need to appendChild on the parent a element.

Comment: I finally had time to test this.

@paulitto & @ Robert Longson
You were totally right, had to append to the parent a element.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working thanks to @paulitto and @Robert Longson

I just had to copy the onMouseEnter eventlistener to the a element.

here is the working code:

```
function MapComponent() {

  function handleHover(event) {
    event.currentTarget.parentElement.appendChild(event.currentTarget);
  }

  return (
    <svg version="1.1" id="World" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
      <a href="/Australia" title="Australia" className="nav-link" 
       onMouseEnter={(event) => handleHover(event)}>
        <path id="Australia" d="..."/>
      </a>
    </svg>
  );
}
```